# Several questions regarding Vim NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

1. Is it possible to set a default directory that the explorer window always opens up in?
2. How do you move cursor from the file explorer to the editor buffer? (on a normal gui-based editor I'd click onto it)
3. How do you move the cursor from the editor buffer thing to the file explorer?

Answer (score 4):

Try typing `?`. Before switching to NERDTree, I recommend first trying Netrw Directory Listing, which comes already installed with Snow Leopard's Vim. I find it sufficient, easier, and faster.

Try this from Terminal:

```
vim ~/Documents/
```

That should open Netrw automatically.

Then, within Vim, type:

```
:h netrw-intro-browse
```

And, read up on how to use Netrw.

To learn how to move your cursor to another window, type:

```
:h windows
```

Then, you'll see `window-move-cursor`, so type `:h window-move-cursor`

It's `CTRL-W j`, where `j` can also be `h`, `k`, or `l`.

Comment: i've looked at that help screen up and down several times. checking out Netrw Directory Listing at the moment.

Comment: The documentation file that is downloaded with NERDTree is more thorough than the ? help. That is more of a quick reference.

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't know of a way to do that, but I recommend bookmarking frequently used folders instead. Once you have created some bookmarks, you can launch NERDTree like this:

```
:NERDTree bookmarkName
```

2 & 3) I prefer to use a separate tab for each file. One you have the cursor next to the file name you want to open within NERDTree, you just press t to open it in a new tab. Although it is true that when you first launch NERDTree it does open a separate buffer in the same tab. I usually immediately press

```
Ctrl-w w
```

to get to the other buffer and close it with :q which will take you back to the file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

**1**.Maybe you didn't got the idea. How do you open the NERDTree? With a `:e` command, using a directory name as argument, right? (remember, the `.` is your current directory). Then, that directory is opened to be visualized in the NERDTree window. Alternatively, you can use the `:NERDTree` command, also giving a directory name as argument and behaving like the previous case. The last option would be to call `:NERDTree` without arguments, and that is the same as passing the `.` argument, according to the help. So, you want to have a default directory, which is technically illogical, if it always open on the directory you asked.

Now, if the problem is that `:NERDTree ~/Desktop<enter>` is so much typing, create a mapping for that.

```
nnoremap ,on :NERDTree ~/Desktop<CR>
```

**2**.You haven't said what kind of Vim flavor you're using. I use a GUI on my Mac called MacVim, and clicking with the mouse works as you expect. Check item 3 as an alternative.

**3**.You can move between windows which contain buffer things with the `<C-W>` family of commands. Read `:h window-move-cursor` to know more, but in your case, if you're with the NERDTree window on the left and the buffer thing on the right, which holds your focus, you can move to the NERDTree window by pressing <kbd>C-W</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>.